# Mouse event is not defined

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, dom-events

I have an HTML5 canvas on a web page, with a JavaScript function that draws an image on the canvas. I'm trying to add a mouse event to the image, so that when it is clicked, another JavaScript function that is called, which will update what is displayed on the canvas.

When viewing the page in Firefox, nothing happens when I click the image that's displayed on the canvas. I'm using Firebug to try and see what's wrong, and it's given me the following message:

```
 mouse_event is not defined
 drawStartButton()index.html (line 107)
 startGame()index.html (line 64)
 (?)()index.html (line 1)
 event = load
 [Break On This Error]  

 ...useX = (mouse_event.clientX-boundingBox.left) * (myGameCanvas.width/boundingBox....

 index.html (line 107)
```

The function I've used to draw the start button on the canvas, and mouse event I've added are below:

```
function drawStartButton(){
            image.onload = function(){
                context.drawImage(image, 260.5, 60);
            };
            image.src = "StartButton.png";
            /** Now I need to add an event listener to the area of the canvas on 
                on which the button image is displayed, in order to 'listen' for 
                a click on the button */
            var boundingBox = myGameCanvas.getBoundingClientRect();
            var mouseX = (mouse_event.clientX-boundingBox.left) * (myGameCanvas.width/boundingBox.width);
            var mouseY = (mouse_event.clientY-boundingBox.top) * (myGameCanvas.height/boundingBox.height);
            var pixels = context.getImageData(mouseX, mouseY, 1, 1); }
```

Basically, all I want to do, is that when the user clicks the button, the function below will be called, and will update the contents of the canvas:

```
function drawLevelOneElements(){
            var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

            /* Draw the images for numbers 1-10.*/
            var image1 = new Image();
            /* Test that this code is being executed */
            context.moveTo(300, 300);
            context.font = "11pt Calibri";
            context.strokeStyle = "black";
            context.strokeText("Testing",300, 300);
            /* End of test */

            image1.onLoad = function(){
                context.drawImage(image1, 50, 50);
                };
            image1.src="1.png";
        }
```

Comment: You never assign anything to `mouse_event`

Comment: Ok, I seem to have fixed the mouse_event part, but I now have another problem with a different part of my code:

The page now loads, with the canvas and the button displayed correctly, however, when I click the button, the console shows an error saying that click is not defined, and that in the function below, 'collides' is not defined. Any idea what I'm doing wrong? The function is:

Comment: function startGame(){
    drawGameElements();
    drawStartButton(); 
    /* Now need to add an event listener to call drawLevelOneElements() when
     the start button is clicked. */
    //myGameCanvas.addEventListener("click", drawLevelOneElements, false);
    //drawLevelOneElements();
    //game_id=setInterval(game_loop, 50);

Comment: /*Add event listener to the canvas */
    myGameCanvas.addEventListener('click', function(e){
     console.log('click: ' + e.offsetX + '/' + e.offsetY);
     var buttonHit = collides(StartButton, e.offsetX, e.offsetY);
     if(buttonHit){
      alert('collision: ' + buttonHit.x + '/' + buttonHit.y);
     } else {
      console.log('no collision');
     }
    }, false);
   }

Comment: Code in comments is unreadable. Either update the question, or (better) answer this question yourself with how you solved it so others can use your findings, and start a new question for the new problem.

Comment: Ok, cheers. Will update the post now.

Answer (score 0):

It seems I was able to solve this by putting the variables mouseX, mouseY and pixels in a function and setting the `boundingBox.onmousemove` property equal to this function:

```
boundingBox.onmousemove = function(e){
                var mouseX = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
                var mouseY = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
                var pixels = context.getImageData(mouseX, mouseY, 1, 1);
            }
```

Comment: [Answered in a question edit and moved  here.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267434/what-is-the-appropriate-action-when-the-answer-to-a-question-is-added-to-the-que)